# If in the pullback p is shrinkable, the p' is shrinkable.

Tags: algebraic-topology

A map $p:E \rightarrow B$ is said shrinkable if $p$ is homotopy equivalent to $id_B$ in $TOP_B$. Show that if $p$ is shrinkable in the
[pullback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy7q6.png)

then $p'$ is shrinkable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a section $s:B\rightarrow E$ of $p$ and a fibre homotopy $G:sp\simeq_B id_E$. Then the pair of the identity $id_{B'}$ and the composite $sf:B'\rightarrow E$ induces a map $s':B'\rightarrow E'$ with $p's'=id_{B'}$. Notice that if $\widetilde p:E\times I\rightarrow B$ is the map $\widetilde p(e,t)=p(e)$, then $E'\times I$ is the pullback of the cotriad $B'\xrightarrow{f}B\xleftarrow{\widetilde p}E\times I$. The map $\widetilde p':E'\times I\rightarrow B'$, $(e',t)\mapsto p'(e')$ together with the composite $E'\times I\xrightarrow{f'\times 1} E\times I\xrightarrow{G}E$ now induce a homotopy $G':E'\times I\rightarrow E'$. It is a fibre homotopy over $B'$ by defintion, and including in at the end points we see that it verifies $s'p'\simeq id_{E'}$.

If you would prefer to work with point sets, then you may find it easier to identify $E'=\{(b',e)\mid f(b')=p(e)\}$ before running the details.